# Authentication in web application

Tags: python, authentication, web.py

I'm making my first web app (python+webpy+mongodb). What's the best way to make authentication module? Should I save login to cookies, or just keep login/pass in variables? Do i have to make every 'restricted' function check user's rights every time it works? Maybe there are any good articles about these things?

Comment: "Maybe there are any good articles about these things?"  Good idea.  Perhaps Google search would reveal a few.  What did you look for?  What kind of search did you try?  What confused you?  http://webpy.org/cookbook/userauth was the first thing I found doing a Google search.  What was confusing about this project?

Comment: i just don't want to take the first solution i have in hand..

Comment: "i just don't want to take the first solution i have in hand"?  Is something stopping you from reading -- perhaps -- two or three and asking **specific** questions.  There are already web.py module for this.  Why aren't you using those modules?

Comment: just to find the most secure way - I'm building a financial app... so security issues are primary

Comment: "Maybe there are any good articles about these things?" Yes.  Google.  Please.  Then.  After reading.  Ask **specific** questions here.

Comment: man.. u r a bit late)) I already got the answer I wanted 6 hours before your first message))))))) anyway ty for comments)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a good guide with explanations: [Form Based Authentication For Websites.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication)

web.py has a [recipe for basic authentication](http://webpy.org/cookbook/userauthbasic) which can be extended using these techniques.

Usually you use a persistence mechanism known as *sessions* to track authenticated users. Have a look at [Beaker](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sessions.html) to see how it can be implemented.

Comment: web.py has its own session module, theres no need in beaker

Comment: If you are interested in basic authentication, here is a quick attribute which you can use to decorate your handlers http://www.varunpant.com/posts/basic-authentication-in-web-py-via-attribute